# VennDiagram R package(How do I use a data file)

Tags: r, csv, venn-diagram

I am trying to make `venndiagram` by using the `VennDiagram` package of R
First I did

```
 CC<- list("123", "221", "231", "324")
 DD<- list("123", "234", "234", "100")
```

`EE` abd `FF` same way( with some common factor)

```
  vi<- venn.diagram(list(CC=CC, DD=DD, EE=EE, FF=FF) , 
                             filename=NULL, fill=rainbow(40)
```

this is giving me a correct venn exactly what I am searching but when I'm writing a CSV file in Excel like this:

```
 CC DD EE FF
 123 112....
 232....
```

and when I load the file using `read.csv`, it is not providing venn!

I converted the csv to a list using `as.list`, but still no luck!

How do I use a file with `venn`?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem. `dat <- data.frame(CC=c(123, 221, 231, 324), DD= c(123,234, 234, 100), EE=c(313, 231, 243, 213)); venn.diagram(as.list(dat), filename='venn2')` I get the file in the working directory.

Comment: What is the output after you try to draw then Venn diagrams from the imported `.csv`? Does it give you an error or is R omitting all output giving you nothing?

Comment: akrun and Olli thanks for your reply if I am writing a list in R as you did it working. but when I am trying to use a file which I made in excel and saved as .csv format it is not working.

Comment: akrun and Olli once again thanks you guys! it worked I just follow as akrun showed here. I was converting a csv file in a list and then I was  uisng it for venn as .list. that was may cause a venn with all zeros. Any way guys thanks a lot for helping me.